# Dynamically update colors of a Google Geochart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm using [Google Geochart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart) and I would like to dynamically change the color of selected regions without having to redraw the entire chart again (which causes the chart to flicker). Is there a way to do this, and if so, how?

Comment: The Geochart API reference doesn't state a `setOptions` method or something. And looking through the source code probably is a pain, knowing it went through the Google Closure Compiler.

Comment: @SimonPlus tell me about it :/

Answer (score 3):

There is way to change the region color of GeoChart dynamically in this [VectorWorkz GeoChart](http://vectorworkz.com/products/geochart/features). Its enables you to change the color of regions dynamically when its bounded data value changes, this is done by using KO, take a look at this [sample](http://vectorworkz.com/demo/Samples/LiveEuropeStockMarketUsingKO.html) and here is the [online demo](http://vectorworkz.com/demo/).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it's impossible to change the colors of regions in Geochart dynamically. However I would recommend you to try [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com) library, which has a `setColors` and `setValues` methods to update data dynamically.